# Flutter release APK is not working but debug APK is working

Tags: android, flutter

My debug APK is working fine but release APK is not working after building it from the command `flutter build apk`. What can be the real issue here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In debug mode, any global variables or methods will work perfectly but in case of release mode, only native code is compiled. So let's assume we are getting some unformatted text and we want to format it and return so if you have a global function to format text like below it will work fine in debug mode but might cause problems in release mode.

Code with global function.

```
// Global Function
String formatText(String unformattedText){
    // ....
    return formattedText;
}

Widget _showFormattedText(String unformattedText) {
   final fd = formatText(unformattedText);
   return Text(fd);
}
```

Instead of this we should follow best practices and wrap everything inside a class which is present globally.

```
// Code with class method.
class CustomFunctions{
  static String formatText(String unformattedText){
      // ....
      return formattedText;
  }
}

Widget _showFormattedText(String unformattedText) {
   final fd = CustomFunctions.formatText(unformattedText);
   return Text(fd);
}
```