# My build release APK from flutter is not working but debug APK is working

Tags: flutter, android-studio, apk, release, flutter-test

I recently completed my app in **Flutter** and I built a release APK. The Build APK is not working at any mobile and it is simply displaying as a **White Screen**. The debug APK in emulator was working fine while the release APK is not working. Can anyone help me out to solve this and Thank you soo much..!!

Comment: Try building it with `flutter build apk --no-shrink`.

Comment: You can find your answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62070879/flutter-release-apk-is-not-working-but-debug-apk-is-working)

Answer (score 4):

If your app requires internet permission, you need to make sure that it's specified. If not given it will still work on debug mode and not on release mode.

Android > App > Src > Main > AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you sign your app correctly?
https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android

Try this to get more informations on what is happening:

```
flutter devices
flutter run -d [deviceID] --release
```

This will run the android app in release mode but you can still see logs